# Split an item on the pipeline

Tags: powershell

I have a text file that will contain something like the similar:

```
Code,Server,Success,Failures
ABC,ABCSRV01,4,5
```

Depending on some logic in the script - the Success or Failure count will get updated. Now at the moment the easiest way I can think of doing this is to:

```
$currentStats = Get-Content "C:\ONL\stats.txt" | Where-Object {$_ -like "ABC,ABCSRV01,*"}
$split = $currentStats.split(",")
$newSuccessCount = $split[2] -as [int]
$newSuccessCount++
$newStats = "ABC,ABCSRV01," + $newSuccessCount + "," + $split[3]
$updatedStats1 = Get-content "C:\ONL\stats.txt" | Where-Object {$_ -notmatch "ABC,ABCSRV01,*"}
$newStatsTxt = $updatedStats1 + $newStats
$newStatsTxt | Out-File "C:\ONL\stats.txt"
```

However, I can't help but feel there must be an easier way of achieving this - maybe on the pipeline?

Comment: Your input file is formatted like a CSV. Using Import-CSV would be most benificial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interacting with your file as an object would be most beneficial to you and your code.

```
$currentStats = Import-Csv "C:\ONL\stats.txt"
```

Then you can access the properties `Success` and `Failures` like object properties. Not sure what you are doing with information but you could just do something like this.

```
$currentStats = Import-Csv "E:\temp\data.txt"
$update = $currentStats | ForEach-Object{

    If ($_.Code -eq "ABC"){
       $_.Success = [int]$_.Success + 1
    } Else {
        $_.Failures = [int]$_.Failures - 1
    }
    $_    
} 
$updatedStats | Export-Csv -Path "C:\ONL\stats.txt"
```

That is, obviously, not what you are going to do but should illustrate the potential you have.

Comment: Completely forgot about the Import-CSV cmdlet !